# Qualcomm USB Driver not recognised for OpenQ 820 (Snapdragon 820) platform after installation

Tags: usb-drive, hexagon-dsp

I am using Open-Q 820(APQ8096) carrier board.  I have installed the Hexagon SDK 3.2 application and its USB driver which is available in the installation path of Hexagon SDK 3.2.
As a result, after installation if I connect OPEN-Q 820 board, it must recognized as

1. Qualcomm USB Composite Device XXXX under Universal Serial Bus controllers in device manager
2. Qualcomm HS-USB Diagnostics xxxx (comx) under Ports in device manager

But here there is no Qualcomm based usb recognised and instead only a standard USB Composite Device was getting listed below the Universal Serail Bus controllers section of the device manager.

To solve this we had followed the readme file which is present in the installation path of Hexagon SDK 3.2 (`Qualcomm\Hexagon_SDK\3.2\tools\debug\usb`) and tried to replace the standard USB Composite Device to Qualcomm based Serial port but it didn't work as expected. The `VID_05C6&PID_9039` doesn't seem to have match in the list of com port in Qualcomm.

I am running windows 10 (64 bit) PC with full USB access.

OPEN-Q 820 Device instance path is mentioned below

```
USB\VID_0BDA&PID_57DE&REV_00147
USB\VID_0BDA&PID_57DE
```

Thank you

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions. More information is available in the [help].

Comment: I have already tried to unisntall and install the drivers but I get the same results

Comment: That has nothing to do with anything. This is the wrong site for the question. As I said, you're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.